# Getting type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int in my flutter project

Tags: flutter

I am having a flutter project, it's been a while though since I opened it. So today I tried to run it and keep getting errors showing

```
type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int'
```

And I don't get any errors before. Though I was using flutter `2.5.0` when it was compiled without errors, now am using flutter `3.0`.

Is the error caused because of my flutter version?

Comment: Can you include more details about the snippet ?

Comment: Maybe include the code part where you're receiving this error?